# Facebook API quit working. why?

Tags: api, facebook

I have an Facebook API that connects to Facebook, pulls the users name, and updates their status.  Up until at least Monday afternoon, it was working properly, but as of Tuesday afternoon, it hasn't worked.  I have tracked it down to the fql_query call in the api file, that is not returning the user info.  When I do a login, I get the user key and the session key just fine, and save them to my DB.  Has there been any API updates?  I checked the forums and there were a handful of post asking why their api's had suddenly quit, but none of them have a reply or resolution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently a Facebook Server issue.  There is no estimated time on when it will be fixed. It maybe a while.